# I cannot update any changes in my android app

Tags: android, updating

I am developing an application in Android but whenever i try to update my application (deleting the old app's files and uploading new files from my pc). After i replace files and re-install my app, i can not see any changes on my phone. It stays like the old version, like no changes are applied.
btw. i change the versionCode and versionName in the manifest file and My app is not on GooglePlay store yet, only in my PC .

Comment: Are you sure you're installing the correct .apk file? How exactly are you installing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to Clean and build the project after u updated the files in your app project if you are using `Eclipse` as an `IDE`.

Comment: I did clean my project but now i cannot see the apk file

Comment: Run the app in Emulator or device from IDE itself

Comment: I cleaned my project and after i run in Emulater i installed and i got it updated now. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean the project **Project --> clean**.
Delete the old project from device and than install new one after cleaning.